# How to show simple REST data in from Ember starter kit?

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I downloaded the [ember starter kit](https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit/archive/v1.0.0-rc.6.zip) and want to show a simple REST API data to see how Ember works.

From videos and tutorials I found that there is a `model` hook that can be used to inject data.

So I did the following:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  model: function ({
    return $.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?oauth_token=TOKENHERE&v=20130723");
  }),
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/'
    })
  })
})
```

And added the following in my `index.html`

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      {{title}}
  </script>
```

However, this didn't work. When I go to `index.html` I don't see anything there. Additionally, under Network tab of Inspect Element, I don't see any network requests being made to the REST API.

What am I doing wrong? Also, for sample purpose I would simply like to have a `data.json` json file that will contain some json data. However, I read that Ember lacks support to read a file, thats why I'm trying a sample rest api provided by foursquare.

Is there a way to read a json file using ember? I'm running this simply on my browser without a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it should work. Here is an example using a different API but using the same structure:

JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js/stats/contributors");
  }
});
```

Templates:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  Ember.js repository contributors
    <ul>
    {{#each user in controller}}
      <li>{{user.author.login}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  </script>
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/448/edit)

Comment: dope. I made the mistake of `Router` vs. `Route`. Also, in your example, how would I show a single random contributor rather than the entire list of contributors. I would just like to pull a random contributor. Is that possible?

Comment: Just use a [computed property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) (updated example: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/450/edit)

Comment: That works great! Not to make things overly complicated but is there a way to reload this data every 2 seconds? barring the pro's and con's of resources. I'd like to reload the random contributors name every 2 seconds.

Comment: There are a couple of examples in this discussion (http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/updating-timeago-when-date-is-not-changing/1401) on the Ember discussion board about using timers to trigger changes in properties, it should get you going in the right direction.